# Center Text in Column

Tags: flutter, dart

How to center the Text in `Column` ?

```
Card(
            child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Image.asset("assets/raining.png")),
          Center(
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                Text("Start Time : " +
                    product.entity.weatherchart[i]['start_time']),
                Text(("End Time : " +
                    product.entity.weatherchart[i]['end_time'])),
              ])),
        ]))
```

Comment: You need  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,`

Comment: @SamChan doesn't work

Comment: Do you have any parent widget for this card?
If yes , share its code and a screenshot of design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change crossAxisAlignment from Start to Center in your Column widget

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
```

Then you need to define a width before Column widget, replace Center widget with a Container (or Expanded, no need to define width when using expanded)

```
 Card(
       child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Image.asset("assets/raining.png")),
            Container( //changed from center
                width: 200, // give width
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, //changed to start
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("Start Time : " +
                        product.entity.weatherchart[i]['start_time']),
                    Text(("End Time : " +
                        product.entity.weatherchart[i]['end_time'])),
                  ]),
            ),
          ]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Card(
        child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Image.asset("assets/raining.png")),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Start Time : "+
                    product.entity.weatherchart[i]['start_time'],
              ),
              Text(("End Time : "+
                    product.entity.weatherchart[i]['end_time']))),
            ]),
      )
    ]))
```